# Import SQL Database through CMD

Tags: mysql, cmd, import, sqlcmd

User: root; Pass:" "; DBname: demodatabase; Filename: demofile;

I am Trying to import very big sql file (972 MB) into my phpmyadmin through CMD. 
I am Using this  code

```
mysql -u root -p dbname < filename.sql
```

After entering the above code cmd asking me the password. "Enter Password:" When I am  Press  ENTER neither error occurs and nor imported data.
sometimes it just blinks and goes to the next line.

https://www.screencast.com/t/7KdszQ0B

Comment: Did you made your criminalcbs empty database ?

Answer (score 0):

try with a GUI tool like
MySQL Workbench if possible

Answer (score 0):

I want to show you how am using my cmd comand line to access my database with using any phpmyadmin
go to windows start page, search for cmd and open it, the first paragraph is what you will see. am using xampp that's why ypu can see xampp on mine you can still change it wamp is your are using the same

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1556]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>cd c:\xampp

c:\xampp>cd mysql

c:\xampp\mysql>cd bin

c:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql.exe -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 8
Server version: 10.4.21-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>

that is how is been done then you can use this command to access you database

1. show databases;
   this command is use to show databases in the phpmyadmin. and remember to press the enter botton for a new command to start. when you press enter the output will appear as this...
   MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;

Answer (score 0):

2.use devclass;
this command line will open the database you want to work with.  eg......

MariaDB [(none)]> use devclass;
Database changed
MariaDB [devclass]>

3. create table class
   now class is the name of the table i want to create the table with the name class but the command line goes like this...
   MariaDB [devclass]> create table class